# Setting environment variables for multiple commands in bash one-liner

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Let's say I have following command

> $>  MYENVVAR=myfolder echo $MYENVVAR && MYENVVAR=myfolder ls $MYENVVAR

I mean that MYENVVAR=myfolder repeats

Is it possible to set it once for both "&&" separated commands while keeping the command on one line?

Comment: You can use grouping, instead of subshell...

Comment: @anishsane — note that if you use: `echo "XYZ=$XYZ"; { XYZ="PQR"; echo "XYZ=$XYZ"; }; echo XYZ="$XYZ"`, then the output after the command grouping `{ … }` is `XYZ=PQR` — what is set in the grouping is set in the main shell because it is _not_ a subshell.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you actually need it as an environment variable (even though the example code does not really need an environment variable; some shell variables are not environment variables):

```
(export MYENVVAR=myfolder; echo $MYENVVAR && ls $MYENVVAR)
```

If you don't need it as an environment variable, then:

```
(MYENVVAR=myfolder; echo $MYENVVAR && ls $MYENVVAR)
```

The parentheses create a sub-shell; environment variables (and plain variables) set in the sub-shell do not affect the parent shell.  In both commands shown, the variable is set once and then used twice, once by each of the two commands.

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses spawn a new process, where you can set its own variables:

```
( MYENVVAR=myfolder; echo  1: $MYENVVAR; ); echo  2: $MYENVVAR;
1: myfolder
2:
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the commands into a string and using `eval` on them is one way not yet mentioned:

```
a=abc eval 'echo $a; echo $a'
a=abc eval 'echo $a && echo $a'
```

Or, if you want to use a general-purpose many-to-many mapping between environment variables and commands, without the need to quote your commands, you can use my `trap`-based function below:

```
envMulti()
{
shopt -s extdebug;
PROMPT_COMMAND="$(trap -p DEBUG | tee >(read -n 1 || echo "trap - DEBUG")); $(shopt -p extdebug); PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND";
eval "trap \"\
[[ \\\"\\\$BASH_COMMAND\\\" =~ ^trap ]] \
|| { eval \\\"$@ \\\$BASH_COMMAND\\\"; false; }\" DEBUG";
}
```

Usage:

```
envMulti a=aaa b=bbb; eval 'echo $a'; eval 'echo $b'
```

Note: the `eval 'echo...'`s above have nothing to do with my script; you can never do `a=aaa echo $a` directly, because the `$a` gets expanded too early.

Or use it with `env` if you prefer (it actually prefixes any commands with anything):

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n\necho $a' > echoScript.sh
chmod +x echoScript.sh
envMulti env a=aaa; ./echoScript.sh; ./echoScript.sh
```

Note: created a test script just to demonstrate usage with `env`, which can't accept built-ins like `eval` as used in the earlier demo.

Oh, and the above were all intended for running your own shell commands by-hand.  If you do anything other than that, make sure you know all the cautions about using `eval` -- i.e. make sure you trust the source of the commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [export](http://bashshell.net/shell-scripts/export-variables-in-bash/) like

```
export MYENVVAR=myfolder
```

then type your commands like `echo $MYENVVAR` (that would work even in sub-shells) etc